# 3 x 8 Contingency Table in Python using actual values from data frame, not counts between the 2 variables

Tags: python

I need a chart in python to display the following data in 3 by 8 form i.e B50, S50, B50-S50 as the rows and Sector as the columns. The crosstab() function gives the correlation or counts between variables, I just need a chart of the following data in 3 by 8 form.

```
   Sector B50      S50             B50 - S50
   x1     19.94    19.00              0.94
   x2     14.09    12.29              1.80
   x3     9.33    10.60              -1.27
   x4     15.63    12.01              3.62
   x5      8.25    17.61             -9.36
   x6      3.81    3.48               0.33
   x7     11.88    12.81             -0.93
   x8     17.25    12.16              5.09
```

​

I tried searching for a python graph that just displays data, but I could not find one to accomplish this simple task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.